# how to handle an array of entries in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a simple blog site, I have a post schema that looks like:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    tags: String,
    category: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Category",
        },
        name: String,
    },
    publishingDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    content: String,
});
```

and my question is: how to handle the category entries?

I'm going to recieve a string of categories and split it by spaces to separate each category, and then I need a function that goes over each 'split' category and check if it exists in my `Category` model (comparing the `name` value , if not it creates it, and then finally pass ALL the category objects whether built or found to the function that is creating the post.

when I had just one category I was able to handle it  by writing a function that checks if the passed category exists or not and then pass the newly created (or maybe found) category to the `Post.create()`

```
Post.create(newPost, function(err, newlyCreatedPost) {
    if (err) {
      // handle the error
    } else {
      // I wrote the 'findOneOrCreate' method as static in 'Category' model
      Category.findOneOrCreate({
        'name': categoryName
      }, function(err, usedCategory) {
        if (err) {
          //
        } else {
          newlyCreatedPost.category = usedCategory;
          newlyCreatedPost.save();
          console.log(newlyCreatedPost);
          res.redirect("/posts");
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

I'm still new to this whole thing of NodeJS,Express and MongoDB (mongoose) so all help or comments are welcomed.

Comment: Each post could have multilple categories , so use Array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use bulk upsert for the category, It'll find an update or create. for more info read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/)

```
Post.create(newPost, function (err, newlyCreatedPost) {
    if (err) {
        // handle the error
    } else {
        var categories = "categorystring".split(' ');

        var bulk = Category.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

        categories.forEach((categoryName) => {
            bulk.find({
                'name': categoryName
            }).upsert().update({
                $set:{'name': categoryName}
            });
        });
        bulk.execute(function (err, usedCategory) {
            if (err) {
                //
            } else {
                // do stuff
            }
        });
    }
});
```